# file path parsed to be variable in R

Tags: r, string, path

I have assigned the path to the variable.

```
               file1 <- "/home/ali/Downloads/data/sample.txt"
```

I want to parse the file path in system function.

```
               var1 <- system("grep -R 'day' file1 | cut -f1", intern=TRUE)
```

How can I parse the value of file1 variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paste to concatenate strings:

```
var <- system(paste("grep -R 'day'", file1, "| cut <etc>"), intern = TRUE)
```